# converting classic PageReference method to @AuraEnabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to convert my existing vf page including controller to the lightning component. I am done with the component but having issue while writing @AuraEnabled method regarding the controller's PageReference method and constructor.

I am inserting opportunity on the "Save" button click in my component.

Button:{!c.saveOpportunity}"

```
//calling the getNewOppId method from NewOpportunityController and referring it to Save Button

    saveOpportunity : function(component,event,helper){
    var action = component.get("c.getNewOppId");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        alert('Inside Callback method');
        if (state == "SUCCESS") {
            var optyId = response.getReturnValue();
            alert(optyId);
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": "/006/o" + optyId
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

I think my method "getNewOppId" which I tried to convert from PageRefrence to @AuraEnabled is not working.

Here is the original page reference method:

```
 public pageReference saveOpp(){
    try{
        Id OpptyOwnerId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: userInfo.getUserId() and IsActive = True LIMIT 1].Id;
        system.debug('++OpptyOwnerId+'+OpptyOwnerId);
        Id RTId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType ='Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id;
        Boolean isRegional = false;
        acc= NEW account();
        acc= [select name,id,Sales_Region__c from Account where id =:oppty.Accountid];
        if(oppty.SMB_OPP_Must_Win_level__c == null)oppty.SMB_OPP_Must_Win_level__c='None';
        if(isRegional )
        oppty.SMB_Opp_Must_Win__c = 'Yes';
        else
        oppty.SMB_Opp_Must_Win__c = 'No';
        oppty.OwnerId = OpptyOwnerId;

       if(REC.name == System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type){
           oppty.StageName = '2 Qualification';
       }else{
           oppty.StageName = '1 Pre-qualification';
       } 
         if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type && acc.Sales_Region__c !='DEF'){ 
            system.debug('----------'+REC.name);               
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'With a Simple DEF record type the account related to the opportunity must be a DEF account.'));
            return null;                                      
        }

         if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type && (oppty.Order_Type__c =='New Customer' || oppty.Order_Type__c =='New Business/GET')){ 
              oppty.Contract_Type__c= 'New';                           
        }else if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type &&(oppty.Order_Type__c =='Renewal/KEEP' || oppty.Order_Type__c =='Organic/KEEP')){
                   oppty.Contract_Type__c= 'Existing';
        }

        insert oppty;

        //partner management evolution
        if(REC.name == System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type){
            SMB_Partner__c insertNoPartner = new SMB_Partner__c(SMB_Opportunity__c=oppty.Id,
                                                                SMB_Name__c=Label.SMB_CL001_No_Partner_ID,
                                                               SMB_Amount__c=0,SMB_Percentage__c=0,
                                                               SMB_Primary__c=true);
            insert insertNoPartner;
        }
        //assign a contact to a new opportunity
        if(conId!=null){
            OpportunityContactRole oppContact = new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=conId,IsPrimary=true,
                                                                           OpportunityId=oppty.Id,Role=Label.Contact_Role);
            insert oppContact;
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + oppty.Id + '?retURL=%2F' + oppty.Id);
           return pageRef;

    }
    catch(exception ex){         
       if(!ex.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'))
       Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Exception Error: ' + ex));                                 
        return null;
    }
     return null; 
}
```

Here is the @AuraEnabled method which I break down from above into getNewOppId and PageReference method SaveOpp() which is calling the getNewOppId().

```
//using Pagereference method to redirecting to the opp detail page

public PageReference saveOpp(){
    Id returnedId = getNewOppId();
    return new PageReference('/'+returnedId);
}

 // Method to get the opportunity Id
@AuraEnabled
public static Id getNewOppId(){
    try{
        Id OpptyOwnerId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: userInfo.getUserId() and IsActive = True LIMIT 1].Id;
        system.debug('++OpptyOwnerId+'+OpptyOwnerId);
        Id RTId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType ='Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id;
        Boolean isRegional = false;
        acc= NEW account();
        acc= [select name,id,Sales_Region__c from Account where id =:oppty.Accountid];
        if(oppty.SMB_OPP_Must_Win_level__c == null)oppty.SMB_OPP_Must_Win_level__c='None';
        if(isRegional )
       oppty.SMB_Opp_Must_Win__c = 'Yes';
       else
       oppty.SMB_Opp_Must_Win__c = 'No';

        oppty.OwnerId = OpptyOwnerId;

       if(REC.name == System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type){
       system.debug('========'+REC.name);
           oppty.StageName = '2 Qualification';
       }else{
           oppty.StageName = '1 Pre-qualification';
       }


         if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type && acc.Sales_Region__c !='DEF'){ 
            system.debug('----------'+REC.name);               
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'With a Simple DEF record type the account related to the opportunity must be a DEF account.'));
            return null;                                      
        }


         if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type && (oppty.Order_Type__c =='New Customer' || oppty.Order_Type__c =='New Business/GET')){ 
              oppty.Contract_Type__c= 'New';                           
        }else if(REC.name ==System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type &&(oppty.Order_Type__c =='Renewal/KEEP' || oppty.Order_Type__c =='Organic/KEEP')){
                   oppty.Contract_Type__c= 'Existing';
        }

        insert oppty;

        //partner management evolution--START
        if(REC.name == System.Label.OAB_Opportunity_Record_Type){
            SMB_Partner__c insertNoPartner = new SMB_Partner__c(SMB_Opportunity__c=oppty.Id,
                                                                SMB_Name__c=Label.SMB_CL001_No_Partner_ID,
                                                               SMB_Amount__c=0,SMB_Percentage__c=0,
                                                               SMB_Primary__c=true);
            insert insertNoPartner;
        }
        //partner management evolution--END

        //assign a contact to a new opportunity
        if(conId!=null){
            OpportunityContactRole oppContact = new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId=conId,IsPrimary=true,
                                                                           OpportunityId=oppty.Id,Role=Label.Contact_Role);
            insert oppContact;
        }

          return oppty.Id;   
    }
    catch(exception ex){        
       if(!ex.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'))
       Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Exception Error: ' + ex));                                 
       return null;
    } 
  }
```

Getting below error when I clicked on the Save button:

```
    Error in $A.getCallback() ['state' is undefined]
Callback failed: apex://NewOpportunityController/ACTION$getNewOppId
```

Please let me know what's wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 1):

It says it in the error message - `state` is not defined.

Define state within the callback like this:

```
action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
  var state = response.getState();
  if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
  ///ect
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I added the state but now getting "internal server error". My getOpportunity() method returning state==="ERROR" instead opportunityId.

Comment: @Ashutosh `internal server error` in this case just means there's a run-time error in your controller action. Check your dev console